# How I can convert TypeScript type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I have the code

```
interface IProps {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

I want to get

```
type Result = {
  key: 'name',
  value: string
} | {
  key: 'age',
  value: number
}
```

Is there any good way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

COnsider this example:

```js
interface IProps {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

type Distribute<Obj, Keys extends keyof Obj> = Keys extends any ? { key: Keys, value: Obj[Keys] } : never

type Builder<T> = Distribute<T, keyof T>

// type Result = {
//     key: "name";
//     value: string;
// } | {
//     key: "age";
//     value: number;
// }
type Result = Builder<IProps>
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N7PQ4m)

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types) you can find more information about distributivity

This line of code `{ key: Keys, value: Obj[Keys] }` is applied to each `IProps` key separately because of distributivity

P.S. There is also an alternative way:

```js
type AlternativeWay<T> = {
    [Prop in keyof T]: {
        key: Prop,
        value: T[Prop]
    }
}[keyof T]


type Result = AlternativeWay<IProps>
```